# External syntax highlighting

Tags: syntax-highlighting, original-vim

Is there a way (even theoretical) for Vim to use an external program for syntax highlighting?

For instance a program that reads buffer content from stdin and prints single-character colour identifiers to stdout (or single-character identifiers for the corresponding `syntax groups`), thus bypassing Vim's usual mechanism for syntax highlighting?

Comment: I found this question on SO: [ANSI color codes in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592715/ansi-color-codes-in-vim) which may be related.

Comment: Only possible via hacks using the already mentioned AnsiEscape or my [colorizer](https://github.com/chrisbra/Colorizer/) plugin. For Files with lots of such syntax highlighting, Vim will become very slow

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that Vim colorization is solely based on the content of the file (and not the output of particular program).

However you could:

- Transform your text using an external program to add color identifiers
- Make a colorization that highlight the text using these identifiers
- Hide these color identifiers to the user

Remark: I believe this is the technique used by [Telescope](https://github.com/nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim) for previewing the files using [bat](https://github.com/sharkdp/bat).

But when you save the file it will be saved using the color identifiers.

Of course you could use a filter to remove these identifier right before saving.

Comment: For example, using `:help textprop`, you could process the results of a program (or daemon using `:help job`) and add highlighting to a buffer.

Comment: Thanks @BenKnoble. I understand my answer is in-precise. Using text properties we can associate properties computed from the output of an external program and based the colorization of these properties instead of the pure content of the buffer.